# how to use html5 and ajax to upload big file?

Tags: javascript, ajax, html

In my company the back-end need to receive file , and they give me the API to send offset and length,but i am not quite family with the file upload , i search in the google,mostly people upload the file to an url ,so i don't know how to solve it .

```
function upLoad($param){
        $conn = new Connection(LEOPARD_SERVER, LEOPARD_PORT);
        $test = new File($conn);

        $result = $test->upload($param['offset'], $param['length']);

        echo json_encode($result);
   }
```

Comment: what is the server side limit?

Comment: @Raghavendra only need to limit the upload file size ,so each chunk size should be 4M